# How to store the a Field(property) into MongoDB from C#, which can have different types?

Tags: c#

Please find the json I'm trying to Store into MongoDb from C#

```
{
  "LocationSection": [
    {
      "Time": "19/08/2022",
      "City": "city1"
    },
    {
      "Time": "19/08/2022",
      "City": [
        {
          "Name": "user1",
          "Street": "21",
          "City": "city2"
        },
        {
          "Name": "user2",
          "Street": "22",
          "City": "city3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In the above JSON, "City" will be either a String or a List.

I tried to store it into MongoDB from C# by creating a model class (mentioned in image)
and by defining "City" property as dynamic.

```
public class Location
{
   public List<LocSection> LocationSection {get; set;}
}
public class LocSection
{
   public String Time {get; set; }
   public dynamic City {get; set;}
}
```

But it is inserted into MongoDB something like this.

```
{
  "LocationSection": [
    {
      "Time": "19/08/2022",
      "City": "city1"
    },
    {
      "Time": "19/08/2022",
      "City": {
        "_t": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[WindowsService.Models.TournamentSQSEvents.CardsMTT, WindowsService]]",
        "_v": [
          {
            "Name": "user1",
            "Street": "21",
            "City": "city2"
          },
          {
            "Name": "user2",
            "Street": "22",
            "City": "city3"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**How to avoid "_t" and "_v" while storing into MongoDB.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to avoid `_t`? Why do you want to?

Comment: It's not appropriate to store "_t" and "_v" right, also  City is stored as an Object, but it has to be stored as either a String or List.

Comment: "_t" is how the C# driver knows what type to deserialize to.

Comment: Why did you add your json as images? It's really not helpful. https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @PalleDue  I removed the images, JSON is added now